# Strange Behaviour of Constraints added Programatically in UITableViewCell | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a `tableViewCell` to which I am giving constraints programatically. I have only a single `ImageView` inside the cell. Now I am not giving cell's `contentView` a fixed height, rather I am giving the `top` & `bottom` of the imageView top `contentView` so that the cell height increase with increase in imageView height.

```
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 15),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -15),
```

Now, giving these constraints, the program is breaking these constraints telling me following:

> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034a4e60 V:|-(15)-[UIImageView:0x7fa7f6605640]   (active, names: '|':Paigham.MessagesTableViewCell:0x7fa7f7809c00'tableCellID' )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034a4f00 UIImageView:0x7fa7f6605640.height == 50   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034a4f50 UIImageView:0x7fa7f6605640.bottom == Paigham.MessagesTableViewCell:0x7fa7f7809c00'tableCellID'.bottom - 15   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003494000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' Paigham.MessagesTableViewCell:0x7fa7f7809c00'tableCellID'.height == 80.5   (active)>"
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000034a4f00 UIImageView:0x7fa7f6605640.height == 50   (active)>

Which I think is a bit strange as tableView cell is getting the proper height from its subviews.
But as soon as I set `tableView` `separatorStyle` to `none`, the constraints aren't breaking anymore. What can be the reason behind that?

My tableViewMethods:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCellID, for: indexPath) as! MessagesTableViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

My customCellCode:

```
  class MessagesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var messagingPersonProfilePicture: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    v.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unnamed-3")
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    v.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return v
}()

 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupMessageCell()
}

func setupMessageCell() {
    contentView.addSubview(messagingPersonProfilePicture)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        messagingPersonProfilePicture.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        messagingPersonProfilePicture.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15),

    ])
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
```

Comment: I think the issue is with 0.5 as per your constraint value should be 80 (15 + 50 + 15) where as UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height is considered as 80.5 which is also active which is causing the issue

Comment: Right, so what do you think that 0.5 is coming from? Any guess? Because I am clueless here!

Comment: Also, I am not giving any estimated height for row.

Comment: did you set  `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` ?

Comment: Can you please post the code where u add imageView as subview to cell and also for height I assume you are returning automatic dimension

Comment: yess @Mat, i did, tried every combination infact!

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, shared!

Comment: try ti remove the comma after your bottomAnchor constraint, I think you added it by mistake

Comment: @Mat, that comma is okay , making no additional problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

After you gave more information about the issue, it seems that your `heightAnchor` definition conflicts with the `TableView` default cell height definition. The conflict occurs because when the `UITableView` first loads/being laid out, it sets the height of its cells to 0. This obviously conflicts with your own constraints(Setting the height to 50 + 15 top + 15 bottom margin). To solve this, you can define the top or bottom anchor with a lower priority.

```
let bottomConstraint = messagingPersonProfilePicture.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15)
bottomConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
bottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Yes I ve already tried to add my subviews into contentView, but got the same result.

Comment: Could you please share your custom cell code, and also the controller's tableview delegate methods ?

Comment: @AbuBäkr the issue with the constraints is only in the terminal or it is visible visually ?

Comment: Its only in the terminal brother! Visually tableview is looking great!